# Is it mandatory to submit iPad compatible app version

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I am about to submit my iPhone app for review.
Was just going through the guidelines for approval on https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html.

> 2.10 iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

What does this mean?
I have not included any iPad feature so far.
Nor I have any graphics for iPad.
I am not intending to release it for iPad. 
(not that I want to restrict it, but I never planned it, and I don't think its necessary as far as my app is concerned)

What should I do?
Is it mandatory to make it 'universal' app?
If yes, what should I ensure?
If no, what should I ensure to make sure 2.10 above is met as far as Apple requirements are concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mandatory to make it universal.

Try downloading and iphone only app and opening it up on an ipad.

It looks like this.

[image]
[image]
You just to make sure it launches and runs normally on an iPad

Answer (score 2):

No. As the guidelines say, it must run *at iPhone resolution and at 2X iPhone resolution*. In other words, in iPad's compatibility mode.

What this means is that you should install your app on iPad and check there's nothing peculiar about it that might make it incompatible in that mode. What it means in practice is not to bother even doing that in most situations: you have to try *really* hard to make an iPhone app incompatible with iPad.